# Home care for possible ringworm while waiting to see the vet

Tags: cats, skin-condition

I brought home two adorable cats from the shelter two weeks ago. The female, Ana, is about 9 months; the male, Professor Paws, about two years.

Unfortunately Professor Paws just started scratching himself and has created a bald spot on his back. I suspect ringworm but of course that's not the only possibility. Unfortunately, these things always seem to happen on a Friday night. Since I don't think this is an emergency, I'll take both of them to the vet on Monday. But is there anything I can do to make him more comfortable in the meantime? I was thinking that a small amount of coconut or olive oil might ease the itching. Of course, it would need to be something that's safe if he licks it.

---

**Update:** Turns out my vet is open on Saturday, so I took both cats in for a check-up. The vet thinks the Professor might have a flea allergy, and putting anything on it would probably just get licked off. Even though he had a flea treatment two weeks ago at the place I adopted him from, my vet gave him an extra treatment, plus antibiotics and something else I forgot and cant read the name of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything can look like ringworm and ringworm can look like anything. It's not a true emergency, but saying that, scratched lesions on pets can get worse very rapidly. Because of licking and safety, I personally would not try any home remedies on these wounds. If you don't have any other choice and it is getting worse you can try some Aloe vera (only) based products, but if he licks those he will potentially froth vigorously from the mouth, but that might distract him from continuing. Some cats will go bezerk though. Under extreme circumstances you can also try to wipe the debris off the wound with a very diluted (1:10) solution of Iodine based liquid (not ointment) antiseptic. It will sting a bit.

Because cat nails are riddled with horrible bacteria, I usually treat these cases with systemic antibiotics as well, which is scheduled.

Also make sure your vet is not open on a Saturday...

Comment: Thank you. I'm keeping a close eye on him, and on the bare spot. The vet is not open on Saturday but does have an emergency number, so I'll call that if needed.

Comment: Wow, the vet IS open on a Saturday, but the info was well-hidden on the website. Thank you for suggesting that.